# Is there any work on the intersection loci of the universal theta divisor with torsion sections?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, shimura-varieties, siegel-modular-forms

Let $Y$ be a Siegel modular variety of some non-stacky level and genus $g$, carrying over it a universal principally polarized family of dimension-$g$ abelian varieties $A\to Y$. Inside $A$, with fine enough level structure, one can define universal theta divisors $\Theta_{\varepsilon,\delta}$ as the zero loci of Riemann's theta functions $\theta[\varepsilon, \delta]$, e.g. see [this survey.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.2734.pdf?origin=publication_detail)

My question is: is there any information about the locus in $Y$ for which some fixed torsion section of $A$ is contained in $\Theta_{\varepsilon,\delta}$? The preceding link has some information about the $2$-torsion, but I was wondering in general.